# Selenium throws ConnectionRefusedError when trying to reopen driver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using the Chrome webdriver with Selenium in Python and I'm running into issues when trying to close/reopen my driver. From google, I guess I'm probably messing up the port number somehow? But I have no idea how or if I can fix that.

Here's the code that I tried to implement:

```
def refreshDriver(driver, url):
print('refreshing driver')
driver.quit()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1680,1050)
trycount=0
success=0
while trycount<20 and success==0:
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        success=1
    except:
        sleep(3)
        trycount = trycount + 1
        if trycount==1:
            print(url)
        print('Retrying Connection... ',trycount)
sleep(.5)
return driver
```

And this is the error I get when executing the line of code after the call to this function occurs:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

What is going wrong? Depending on where in my code I put that snippet, it works or it throws this error and I'm not sure why. I'm at a total loss. If it's because the port number is changing, how do I fix this?

Thanks!

PS. If you're wondering why I'm closing and reopening my webdriver in the first place, it's because my script is very long and accumulates HUGE Chrome memory, causing it to slow to a stop. I'm attempting to relieve this by restarting chrome after visiting any particularly large pages.

Comment: Selenium API will manage the port automatically. I think your code should work fine. Does it throw error at the first loop?

Comment: The Try/Except is there because originally it would throw the error right within the code. But since trying to place the code in an actual function (because I had it written all over the place) now it runs the function just fine but then throws an error in a strange place. After refreshing the webdriver, it gets new elements from the page but then crashes in different places. One run crashed waiting for staleness of an element (It's definitely stale, the browser is closed) so I took that line out and it made it a little further before crashing within the Try/Except code of my function.

Comment: at which line you are getting error. if it's before the loop you are trying to create driver, could your put some sleep after `driver.quit()`, also could you try to kill the chromdriver process as well if this doesn't work. By the way I tested your code and it works perfectly. So putting selenium and chromedriver version might help.

Comment: If I get an error in the actual function (as opposed to after the call, someplace else in my code) it fails on the call to `driver.get(url)`, claiming the target machine "actively refused" a connection.  But I only get this error sometimes, depending on where in my code I place the call to `refreshDriver()`. I think it may raise the problem when I try to call it within another function, could that be? It makes no sense to me... Even when it looks like it starts working, my code crashes an hour or two into my test with that same error, out of the blue...

Comment: What browser you are using? What type of locator (xpath, css selector, id, etc.)? How many elements did it find? The webdriver might be crashed because of these factors.

Comment: I'm using ChromeDriver 2.29.461591.  My actual Chrome browser is 56.0.2924.76 if that matters. Selenium (for python 3.6.0) is version 3.4.3. All of my locators are using CSS.

Comment: I'm still getting ConnectionRefused errors in seemingly mundane locations. I don't understand what's causing it so I can't figure out how to properly fix it. Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: I'm running into the same error trying to run multiple instances of selenium/chrome in different threads.

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: It's been a year so I don't fully remember, but I think I basically just had to break up my test runs so it wasn't running for hours and hours, and keep an eye on it, writing results as I go and making it easier to start where I left off. Selenium was great, but also kind of glitchy. Even in the end, it was unreliable and had to be watched to make sure it was running right. Sorry I can't be more helpful.